# Interpreting UTF-8 unicode strings in c++

Tags: c++, unicode

Currently coding in C++20 using WSL2 Ubuntu, G++.

If I had a .txt file consisting of utf-8 unicode characters:

```
▄  ▄ ▄▄▄ ▄   ▄   ▄▄▄▄  ▄▄  ▄   ▄ ▄▄▄
```

1. How can I get the length (number of unicode characters) of this unicode string?
2. How can I read the file content and print out the unicode string?

Comment: Unicode characters is not actually telling anything. You have to know or determine file encoding first. Strictly speaking Utf-8 is unicode, UTF-16LE is Unicode, UTF-32 is Unicode - so the real question that needs answer first is which unicode was it. Because it is very likely that you will have to do conversion yourself

Comment: How do I find out which encoding is being used?

Comment: Sometimes the first few bytes of the file tells you. Other times you have to do some amateur crypto and try them all until you find a decoded message that makes sense.

Comment: There is also [ICU library](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/howtouseicu.html) that produces somewhat good results on files. I am using that library myself as I was lasy to write something elaborate

Comment: I compared the binary of a single character to the unicode table, and it looks like its using the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Locklan You are still in deep trouble. The next set of questions is: What system are you developing on, what compiler do you use, what's the encoding of your source file?
It's all important because depending on this it may not even come down to doing anything to drastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `stdout` supports UTF-8 (on Windows you can get by with `chcp 65001` at the cmd prompt)
- We're counting Unicode code points, not glyphs made up of multiple code points.

UTF-8 encoding consists of start bytes following the bit patterns:

1. `0xxxxxxx` (single byte encoding)
2. `110xxxxx` (two-byte encoding)
3. `1110xxxx` (three-byte encoding)
4. `11110xxx` (four-byte encoding)

Follow-on bytes use `10xxxxxx` as a bit pattern.

UTF-8 can be read using `std::string` and the bytes processed accordingly.

Demo code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("input.txt");
    string s;
    getline(f,s);
    cout << "string: " << s << endl;
    cout << "length(bytes): " << s.length() << endl;

    int codepoints = 0;
    for(auto b : s) {
        if((b & 0xC0) != 0x80) // not UTF-8 intermediate byte?
            ++codepoints;
    }

    cout << "length(code points): " << codepoints << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
string: ▄  ▄ ▄▄▄ ▄   ▄   ▄▄▄▄  ▄▄  ▄   ▄ ▄▄▄
length(bytes): 72
length(code points): 36
```